# World Pay Error message: You must enable SSL check in production mode

Tags: ssl, production, worldpay

I'm using Worldpay API with 'OwnForm' for card payments, (https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/own-form). It's works perfect on test environment. but on live environment, I'm getting following error,

Error message: You must enable SSL check in production mode

My website has already SSL Certificate (https://)

Can anyone suggest the solution or reason for this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

In WorldPay library find following code line in connection.php,

```
private $ssl_check = false;
```

and change it to true

```
private $ssl_check = true;
```